# How to create modules in spring

Tags: java, spring

I am a very very beginner with Spring. And I need to understand how the following problem is soled in Spring.

Lets suppose I have a two pages - `cars` and `car`. On `cars` page list of all cars is generated and user can apply different filters. On `car` page user can read information about certain car. These are main parts of two pages.

However, both pages contain and two additional modules, lets say ads, and last user comments. Every module has its own logic and can use data from url/post/get. I mean

```
-------------------------
|  ----------           |
|  | Ads    |           |
|  ----------    Car[s] | 
|  ----------    Page   |
|  | Comms  |           |
|  ----------           |
-------------------------
```

So we see that in result we have two pages and some shared modules. Of course the code of these modules mustn't be duplicated for every page. How are such shared components are created in Spring? Please, give at least the name of the method/component, the rest I can read in internet.

Comment: That's the responsibility of the view component. Which view technology do you use?

Comment: @Henry I plan to use JSP. But I don't think that it is right to put module logic in view.

Comment: Not the business logic, but the view part of the module. For JSPs you can use includes to have the module specific parts just once. On the controller side use a common method to build the model part used by the module view.

Comment: @Henry Thank you for your answer. I understand your approach. But this is what I don't want to do. I don't want to mix module business logic with main page business logic. I want to separate them and I think there are possible solutions in Spring to do it.

Answer (score 2):

From the backend side you can create request mapping for

1. `@Path(/Cars) ModelAndView cars(...)`
2. `@Path(/Car) ModelAndView car(id)`
3. `@Path(/Ads) ModelAndView ads(...)`

Each path will be connected with handler which could return `ModelAndView` object. When you will send a request for `/cars` you handler method will do some operations and also it can invoke method handler for each `/car` - `car(id)` and also `ads()`.

```
ModelAndView cars(ids) {
   doRequestSpecificOps()
   result = new ModelAndView()
   foreach id in ids
       result put car(id)

   result put ads()
   return result
}
```

From the frontend side you should separate each representation block. It depends on your framework.